# Control over names and form of Java beans serialization?

Tags: xml, xml-serialization, javabeans

I wrote a quick serialization routine using XMLEncoder and got the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.7.0_25" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
 <object class="edu.stevens.Test">
  <void property="id">
   <int>1</int>
  </void>
  <void property="name">
   <string>Fred</string>
  </void>
 </object>
</java>
```

I would like to define tags that are more meaningful, not to mention more compact.  Something like this:

```
<Test>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>Fred</name>
</Test>
```

I would not mind embedding the package names in the file once, but don't want it replicated every time since it can get huge.

Obviously, I could do this by letting serialization do its thing, then run an XSLT translation step afterward, but that is slow and cumbersome.

If there is any way to define mappings of tags to objects, that would be my number one choice.  If not, is there any other XML serialization tool that would work?

In the general case, we need objects containing objects, like this:

```
<Quiz>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>foo</name>
  <Question>
    <id>1</id>
    <text>What kind of question is this?</text>
    <audio>foo.mp3</audio>
    <MultipleChoice>
      <Answer correct="t">rhetorical</Answer>
      <Answer>stupid</Answer>
      <Answer>funny</Answer>
    </MultipleChoice>
    <text>another part to this question, what is 2+2?</text>
    <Fillin>
      <id>2</id>
    </Fillin>
  </Question>
</Quiz>
```

I would prefer to be able to serialize with attributes:

but if it is more difficult, then it is not a big deal.

Comment: You don't need to deserialize ? XSLT is my first idea. You can write your own XML serializer using Introspection. I can write you a sample if needed.

Comment: We need to serialize java objects into a known (preferably human-specified) XML form, and then yes, use that XML to load back into java objects.

There is no question that the java beans serialization would work, but it is ugly and much bigger than we want.

Comment: So, do you want a kind of custom xml serializer/deserializer ?

Comment: I would prefer to use a prebuilt serializer for ease of development, but if it isn't possible to achieve, I would like to see your concept for a serializer.  The writing is easy, it is the parsing that is the hard part.

Comment: The prebuilt serializer will need the full class name to load the write class (can't be done using XSL to retrieve the original XML, or with hardcoded replacement). Their is many way to do a custom serializer : un-protect private/protected property at runtime OR inherit all Class to serialize with a root Class. Not so easy in any cases.

Comment: If I made a mapping:
edu.stevens.Quiz ->Quiz  and on the way out, the opposite, then I could in fact generate a smaller representation.  I can edit the question to show this.  But you said you would show a way to write a custom serializer, and I Would definitely like to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my sample of custom serialize/deserialize to/from XML.

Run the code here: http://ideone.com/H3oHBn

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


public class CustomSaveLoad {

    static class Container {
        Container Container1;
        Container Container2;
        AnotherContainer AnotherContainer;
        String name;
    }

    static class AnotherContainer {
        String name;
        int value;
    }

    static Document save(Object obj) throws Exception {
        Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();

        save(obj, obj.getClass().getSimpleName(), doc, doc);

        return doc;
    }

    static void save(Object obj, String name, Node parent, Document doc) throws Exception {     
        Class<?> objCls = obj.getClass();

        Element elt = doc.createElement(name);
        parent.appendChild(elt);
        if (objCls.getCanonicalName().startsWith(CustomSaveLoad.class.getSimpleName())) {
            for (Field field : objCls.getDeclaredFields()) {
                Object value = field.get(obj);
                if (value != null) {
                    save(value, field.getName(), elt, doc);
                }
            }
        } else {
            elt.setTextContent(obj.toString());
        }
    }

    static <E> E load(Document doc, Class<E> cls) throws Exception {
        Element elt = doc.getDocumentElement();
        E obj = cls.newInstance();
        load(obj, elt);
        return obj;
    }

    static void load(Object obj, Element elt) throws Exception {
        Class<?> cls = obj.getClass();
        NodeList children = elt.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
            if (children.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element childElt = (Element) children.item(i);
                Field field = cls.getDeclaredField(childElt.getTagName());
                Class<?> childCls = field.getType();
                if (childCls.getCanonicalName().startsWith(CustomSaveLoad.class.getSimpleName())) {
                    Object childObj = childCls.newInstance();
                    field.set(obj, childObj);
                    load(childObj, childElt);
                } else {
                    String value = childElt.getTextContent();
                    if (childCls == String.class) {
                        field.set(obj, value);
                    } else {
                        childCls = toWrapper(childCls);
                        Method method = childCls.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);
                        field.set(obj, method.invoke(null, value));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static Class<?> toWrapper(Class<?> cls) {
        if (cls.isPrimitive()) {
            if (Integer.TYPE == cls) {
                cls = Integer.class;
            } else if (Double.TYPE == cls) {
                cls = Double.class;
            }
        }
        return cls;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Container rootContainer = new Container();
        rootContainer.name = "root";
        rootContainer.Container1 = new Container();
        rootContainer.Container1.name = "root.c1";
        rootContainer.Container2 = new Container();
        rootContainer.Container2.name = "root.c2";
        rootContainer.AnotherContainer = new AnotherContainer();
        rootContainer.AnotherContainer.name = "root.c3";
        rootContainer.AnotherContainer.value = 42;
        rootContainer.Container2.AnotherContainer = new AnotherContainer();
        rootContainer.Container2.AnotherContainer.name = "root.c2.c3";
        rootContainer.Container2.AnotherContainer.value = 21;

        Document doc = save(rootContainer);

        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        transformerFactory.setAttribute("indent-number", 2);
        Transformer transform = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transform.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transform.transform(new DOMSource(doc), result);

        String xml = result.getWriter().toString();

        System.out.println("Saved to xml:");
        System.out.println(xml);

        Container loadedContainer = load(doc, Container.class);
        System.out.println(loadedContainer.Container2.AnotherContainer.value);
    }

}
```

Comment: This dynamic approach is really elegant.  I am wondering whether I might prefer to do a compiler, where the dynamic code generates Java source that serializes the object.  That will be about 50x faster than the serialization.  But for sheer elegance, this is beautiful and compact.

Comment: I will just follow up with another question if I decide to build a compiler and have some trouble.  Your code is perfect and deserves and immediate thumbs up!